# How does spanner.Mutation understand which row to update

Tags: go, google-cloud-spanner

From the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/spanner@v1.38.0#hdr-Updating_a_row):

> Changing the values of columns in an existing row is very similar to inserting a new row:
>
> ```
> m := spanner.Update("User",
>   []string{"user_id", "profile"},
>   []interface{}{UserID, profile})
> _, err := client.Apply(ctx, []*spanner.Mutation{m})
> ```

How does the Spanner understand which row to update? I'm seeing like it is missing `WHERE` clause. Does it automatically use some fields as the key (like implicit `user_id = "..."`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Spanner will automatically use the primary key of the table that the mutation is updating. This means that you must include all the columns of the primary key in an `Update` mutation. One `Update` mutation will therefore also only update one row (and it will return a `NOT_FOUND` error if the row does not exist).

This also means that it is not possible to update the primary key value of a row. Instead, you must delete the row and insert a new one if you want to 'change' the primary key value.

See https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rpc/google.spanner.v1#mutation for more information on how mutations work.

Comment: Can you link to some documentation confirming this, if possible?

Comment: And does that essentially mean one can't update the primary key?

Comment: Correct, the primary key value cannot be updated. I've also added a link to the documentation.

Comment: Does that also mean that key fields always must be included and the mutation will fail otherwise?

Comment: yes, an Update mutation must include a value for all primary key columns, and it will fail otherwise.